# Multimedia keys in Ubuntu stopped working

Tags: shortcut-keys, multimedia

my multimedia keys stopped working in Ubuntu, it used to work just fine (Clementine, Rhytmbox) now nothing, even custom mapping in Clementine does not work.

It is still working in KDE. Any ideas?

Comment: In my case it was just a matter of rebooting. It was with other keyshortcuts too, like the ones for gnome-screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to figure out it an hour, and just after i post question...

i resolved it by this command:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
```

which should resed keys. Weird that did not work by hand.